# Different height being used by UL than specified in DIV

Tags: html, css

I've set the DIV height to 54px but for some reason the UL is only about half of that - all the navigation links are way up at the top of the div for some reason.

```
  <div id="menu">
    <ul class="left" style="display: none;">
      <li id="dashboard"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" class="top"><?php echo $text_dashboard; ?></a></li>
    </u>
  </div>
```

Here's what's in my CSS that I think pertains to this:

```
#menu {
    background: url('../image/menu.png') repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 54px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    min-width: 900px;
}
#menu > ul.left {
    float: left;
}
#menu > ul.right {
    float: right;
}
#menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../image/transparent.png');
}
#menu > ul a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu > ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu > ul > li + li {
    background: url('../image/split.png') center left no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul .top {
    padding: 10px 15px 9px 17px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu > ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#menu > ul ul li {
    padding: 2px;
    clear: both;
}
#menu > ul .selected .top {
    background: url('../image/selected.png') repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu > ul .parent {
    background-image: url('../image/arrow-right.png'); 
    background-position: 95% center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul li ul ul {
    margin: -29px 0 0 161px;
}
#menu > ul li li a {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    width: 147px;
}
#menu > ul li li > a:hover {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #BD4C14;
    background-color: #391706; 
}
```

Any idea what needs to be changed to extend the height of the UL like I did the DIV?

Comment: Try looking at your element in Chrome by right clicking then choosing 'inspect element'.  Check out EXACTLY what CSS is affecting your element to the right of the screen.

Comment: Did you clear your floats? It doesn't look like it.